# `ld` says it places a variable somewhere, but places it elsewhere

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, segmentation-fault, ld

For an embedded application, I have a certain section in program memory, which I would like to hold a collection of state variables.

I want this section to be called ".mysect", and be placed at `0x01000000` in program memory.

I declare a variable:

```
int myVar __attribute__((section(".mysect")));
```

I pass linker options like so:

```
-Wl,--section-start=.mysect=0x01000000 -Wl,-Map,a.map
```

I look in a.map:

```
.hooksect    0x0100212c 0x4114 ./build/myobj.o
             0x0100212c               myVar
```

Ok, looks good. The linker stuck 'myVar' into the right spot in memory. Time to run the program.

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Interesting, and gdb says that it segfaults when accessing the area of `.mysect` that is supposed to contain `myVar`. Where is myVar located?

```
(gdb) print &myVar
$1 = 0x2b00212c
```

It's a similar story with every other variable in `.mysect`.

So, every member of that section has been shifted up by 0x2a000000 bytes, and trying to access the nominal location of `.mysect` results in segfault.

Any thoughts as to what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/Wj9rcT4vr

Comment: It's probably something else that I'm doing. There really should be nothing wrong with this, and your godbolt snippet supports that.

Comment: Worth noting that the output of the link map agrees with what is printed on godbolt, as well

Comment: Would you mind to provide a [mre], with emphasis on "complete"? Does the linker map tell you something more, have you read all of it?

Comment: The issue I have is that this is proprietary software that I'm working on. I'm comfortable sharing an \_\_attribute__ tag or a few linker flags with variable names obscured, but not much more than that. There are also a lot of moving parts to it - it could be a lot of things. I'll accept it if the question is closed.